# Parse string with two sets of delimiters to form an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, text-parsing, delimited

**Input:**

```
$this->request->get(['opt']) = '337:230,323:112';
```

**My Current Code:**

```
$option = explode(",", $this->request->get['opt']);

foreach ($option as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . "<br>";       
}
```

**My Results:**

```
337:230
323:112
```

**Question:**
How can I separate the above data into an associative array?

**Desired Result:**

```
[
    337 => 230, 
    323 => 112,
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to explode again on the colons, so perhaps something like [this](https://3v4l.org/UbdYh)?

```
<?php

$opt = '337:230,323:112';

$option = explode(",", $opt);

foreach ($option as $pair) {
    list(key, $value) = explode(':', $pair);
    $array[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($array);
```

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [337] => 230
>     [323] => 112
> )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sscanf()` while iterating over the comma-exploded pairs of values will ensure that your data pushed into the result array will be cast as integers.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lutgt))

```
$string = '337:230,323:112';

$result = [];
foreach (explode(',', $string) as $pair) {
    [$k, $result[$k]] = sscanf($pair, '%d:%d');
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  337 => 230,
  323 => 112,
)
```